# bootstrap 3.2 header broken in firefox and IE. Works fine in chorme + opera

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's the [link](http://isotopethemes.com/extenso/home3.html)

The header works perfectly on chrome + opera but is broken on firefox + IE. This is build using bootstrap 3.2. I've spent 2 hours to solve this but could not find any issues in code.

may be I missed something, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your CSS.
Remove margin bottom from ".h3_lang_list" and ".h3_lang_list li" elements and slider should be ok.

Comment: There is also problem with font-face. Check if you have linked fonts correctly.